# Posting answers via Stack Exchange API

Tags: support, api, write-access

Can I post answers via an app using the API, is it possible? And if so, what are the limitations; linked with the reputation of users?

So if someone has 1 reputation he can also post answers, like a higher reputation user?
Can I retrieve all answers for a question?

Answer (score 3):

It is not currently possible.

At the moment it is only possible to post comments with the API.

(and when/if posting answers can be done using the API, it will follow the restrictions of the site, if not even stricter)